# IntelliJ prevents Refactor (moving a package elsewhere) : multiple directories correspond to package

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx, refactoring

So I want to do a little bit of Refactoring in my LibGDX project. Part of the structure looks like this:

[image: project structure]

When I want to drag `renderers` into `rendering`, this warning message pops up:

[image: Warning message: Multiple directories correspond to package]

`Multiple directories correspond to package`. It points to my `jar` files, somehow. Yet, those are located within folders on which I have set `Mark as Excluded`:

[image: Excluded directories]

Anyhow, clicking `Yes` on the Warning message gives me this error:

[image: Error message: read-only packages]

All of this prevents me from refactoring as I wish.

A weird bug. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try cleaning the repository with Gradle see if it helps

Comment: @OlivierL.Applin yes, it works. However, this is more of a hack than an actual permanent solution, I think. Why would a generated and excluded `jar` be modified when I try to refactor my code?

Comment: your compiled .class files are actually included in the .jar file. So it should effectively contains your package `renderers`. My guess is that maybe IntelliJ tries to apply that refactoring to thoses file as well

Comment: Is it possible to provide little sample project where the issue is reproduced for you? Thanks

Comment: @OlgaKlisho it would be hard to do so. I could revert commits and clone, but even then, some files were excluded from the commits so some things would actually be missing anyway. I do not know specifically what sequence of actions I did to bring me there.

Comment: if possible can you please check if the issue is reproduced for you with IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2019.3+EAP)? Please also see the issue that seems to be similar to yours: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139252